# How to get API value in jsx in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

How to get API value in jsx in ReactJs? I'm getting all the values from API. But not able to print it in the UI. Can anyone please help?

My Code:

```
...
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search_event: '',
      lists: []
    };
  }
...
componentDidMount() {
     var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
     var input = this.state.search_event;
     axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'v1/events/?on_dashboard=false'+input)
     .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.events_count; i++) {
          var obj = response.data.events[i];
          console.log(obj);
        }
        list: response.data.events;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
...
return(
    <div>
                {this.state.lists.map(function(list){
                  return(
                    <div>{list.name}</div>
                  );
                })}
                {/*here I want the values*/}
              </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use response in render, you should set response to state. Then you can loop through the events object to render. Like this

```
    constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search_event: '',
      lists: [],
      events: []
    };
  }
...
componentDidMount() {
     var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
     var input = this.state.search_event;
     var events = axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'v1/events/?on_dashboard=false'+input)
                                         .then(function (response) {
                                            return response.data.events;
                                          })
                                      .catch(function (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                      });
     this.setState(events: events);
  }


 render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.lists.map(function(list){
              return(
                <div>{list.name}</div>
              );
            })}
            {this.state.events.map(function (event) {
                return (
                    <div>{event.name}</div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Comment: No problem it's okay

Comment: now error gone but nothing id getting printed in my UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157895/discussion-between-narasimha-reddy-and-riya-kapuria).